# A better way to use global objects using Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework2

After doing some R&D I found that Zend\I18n will be best option available to use with-in my application for translation purposes. But I am having a major issue i.e it seems that I have to instantiate a new instance of translation whenever I need translation. A quick dirty way is to use global object and I am not going to use that. I am using Zend components e.g Zend Loader + Zend I18N only.

The question is how to manage global objects given zend framework. I don't want to change class constructors for dependency injection.Please provide me some suggestion.

**Edit**

As someone suggested using Zend_Registry but that is deprecated in Zf2.However, closely related thing  in Zf2 is ServiceManager. But I am not getting a good example of how to initialize a ServiceManager at application level and use it to get global translation service ( if I am right ).

Comment: Dependency injection is the solution, and you've said you don't want to do that.

Comment: @TimFountain thanks , unfortunately I have lots of classes

Comment: Considering I18n is supposed to be a thing of the VIEW and you have `$this->translate()` for that, I don't understand the need of having a "global object". If ever you need the i18n component in your controller, just write yourself a controllerplugin that gets the i18n stuff. If you need it elsewhere, you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Sam , my application is not fully MVC structure like Zend views etc. I am trying to embed it into my application. So I am not using Zend views/forms etc, just some required components. If that is costly I ll stop the idea of embedding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classes like translator in global scope you should use `Zend_Registry`.

All you have to do is set registry value with:

```
Zend_Registry::set('translator', $translator)
```

then you can get your instance from anywhere:

```
$translator = Zend_Registry::get('translator');
```

Of course 'translator' instance is just an example. You can get more detail in manual [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.registry.using.html)

Comment: This applies to ZF1, but this question was tagged for ZF2, which doesn't have a registry class.

Comment: so in ZF2 Zend_Registry is depricated , too bad :(